# Is there any software to track user activity on Mac OS Server?

Tags: macos, osx-server, user-account

I'm running a Mac server in my office with the following set up

- Mac Mini with macOS High Sierra 10.13.2
- Apple Server 5.4
- NAS unit

On this system, we have a number of users connecting into it on a regular basis which we want to track all of their activity including logging on and off the server, which files they access and any other details we can possibly trace (as much detail as possible).

My question to the community is - does anyone know of any software that can actually do this?

All recommendations would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: See this related post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304893/find-out-if-any-files-were-exported-from-my-macbook/304981#304981

Comment: Why would someone want to do this?

Comment: @not2savvy Usually to comply with laws

Comment: @not2savvy - There's a range of reasons for user auditing from simple activity monitoring (what was so-and-so doing on the server) to policy/regulatory compliance (like [HIPAA](http://whatishipaa.org/) in the US).  You want to be able to audit who accessed what for compliance purposes.

Comment: [This Apple Community thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7137465) has clues on how to turn on logging of some sort. I don’t know if it applies to your server version, although I would be surprised if it doesn’t work.