# Is there a way to see when an application was launched?

Tags: logs, console, history

Is there a way to see when an application was launched? I need to restore some tabs that were open in my browser when I launched it several weeks ago (it is still running) and I want to look in the browser history at the "launch moment".

I took a quick look in Console.app but there was just too much information.

It is about Firefox. I launched a couple of weeks ago and have since then closed a few tabs that were open when I launched and that I would like to restore. Everytime you launch and restore previous session there is an entry for each tab in the browser history. If I just could find this moment it would be easy to find my lost tabs

Comment: so it is a web based app ? what browser is it

Comment: @Buscar웃 Web based app? No it is just Firefox. I launched a couple of weeks ago and have since then closed a few tabs that were open when I launched and that I would like to restore. Everytime you launch and restore previous session there is an entry for each tab in the browser history. If I just could find this moment it would be easy to find my lost tabs.

Comment: @DaniilManokhin Could be a duplicate but that answer doesn't work for me. The column mentioned there is completely empty on my computer.

Comment: You have to turn on Auditing.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304981/119271

Comment: @Allan turn on Auditing for Firefox history ? that is a new one. I did not know about that.

Comment: What Application are you talking about ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 -  Firefox history doesn't tell you when it (the app) was launched.  To get the launch timestamp, auditing must be turned on.  If it was, he can then identify the when it was last started then search his history at or near that date.

Comment: There is some confusion here. So you launched some app (that you wont tell us about) and that app opened some Tabs in Firefox. Now you want to know using Firefox when this secret app was launched ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 How are you reading things!?!? I opened Firefox and restored the previous session. End of story.