# Is there a log of all the apps I am running on my macOS?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation

I think being able to see what apps I use the most on a daily/weekly/monthly/yearly basis would be a good idea for macOS users.

Are there such applications already available or a log file / resources from the OS where we could extract this information?

Comment: In the top menu bar: Apple / Recent Items

Comment: And if you have macOS Catalina, I believe ScreenTIme may do at least some of what you ask.

Comment: I haven’t tried this in Mojave or Catalina (yet), but you could consider [enabling auditing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304981/119271).

Comment: Screen Time on macOS reports time on any open app which you may not be using. For example, if you open an app and ignore it while working on something else, Screen time will report time for the backgrounded app. This is not what I am looking for here. I want to automatically keep track of any app I have in the foreground and get stats on that.   I actually decided to make this. Working on it.